# What technologies are used for building custom 3D launchers for Android?

Tags: android, 3d, launcher

I am a Java developer and I am starting off with Android development. I have done few simple android apps both native and phonegap. As a hobby project, I am planning to develop an Android 3D launcher (something like [Next 3D launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gtp.nextlauncher)). However, I have the following questions.

- I am not sure what technologies are used for developing such launchers.
- Can it be built using web technologies only? (e.g. HTML5, CSS3, JQuery Mobile and phonegap)
- If we need to do build a native App, what technologies can be used for 3D animations and transitions?

I am fine to learn all the required technologies to achieve my hobby project. I would be grateful if you could guide with the list of technologies and samples if any.

Note: I have looked at Android default launcher etc. I am most interested in 3D launchers.

Thanks